# How to avoid "Sending 'geolocationDidChange' with no listeners registered" warning in react native?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, react-native

I am going to get current location in react native.

I was used below code:

```
    if(Platform.OS == "android") {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    'title': 'Location Permission',
                    'message': 'Wichz would like to access your location to get your things.'
                }
            )
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                // console.warn("You can use locations ")
            } else {
                // console.warn("Location permission denied")
            }
        } catch (err) {
            // console.warn(err)
        }
    }
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedLat: position.coords.latitude,
            selectedLng: position.coords.longitude
        });
        Global.selectedLat = position.coords.latitude;
        Global.selectedLng = position.coords.longitude;
        this.getcurrent_address(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }, (error)=>console.log(error.message),
    {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 3, maximumAge: 1, distanceFilter: 1}
    );
```

And add Location usage description like below in ios project:
[image: location description screenshot]

It works well on both ios and android, but I have get warning box like below:

[image: warning box]

How can avoid this warning box? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably too late now but I'll just detail my experience with this warning for those people in the future that have this same issue.

I encountered this error myself before. For me the cause of this warning is basically that the component is re-rendered before geolocation watchPosition call is fully completed.

In my case, it was because I had multiple fetch calls that caused the component to be re-rendered in quick succession. I fixed it by making geolocation watchPosition only be called on the final render of the component.